# Declare an array as a class member

Tags: c++, arrays

I build two classes, cell, and HashTable, I want to declare an array of cells as a hashTable class member.

I want to do it with primitive vars like int,chars, like I declare array of cars as a hashTable class member.

I tried to declare an array of cells in some ways :

```
1.
class HashTable{
    public:
    int size;
    int numOfKeys;
    Cell* table = new Cell[10];
    int cars[4];
    //static void resize(HashTable &ht);
    static void reinsert(Cell* new_table, int new_size, Node<Player*> *data);
    HashTable() : size(10), numOfKeys(0) {
       table = new Cell[10];
    }


2. class HashTable{
    public:
    int size;
    int numOfKeys;
    Cell* table = new Cell[10];
    int cars[4];
    //static void resize(HashTable &ht);
    static void reinsert(Cell* new_table, int new_size, Node<Player*> *data);
    HashTable() : size(10), numOfKeys(0),table(new Cell[10]) {
      
    }
```

I try to declare it in the constructor but it doesn't work.
How am I supposed to define this array?
Thanks !
I don't see any error , but I can see the array of cars but not the array of table [image]

```
class Cell
{
public:
    AVLTree<Player*>* AllPlayers;
    int treeSize;
    Cell() : treeSize(0) {
         AllPlayers = new  AVLTree<Player*>();
    }

    ~Cell(){
        delete AllPlayers;
    };

    Cell(const Cell &sec) = default;

    Cell &operator=(const Cell &sec) = default;

    void reinsert(Player* pl)
    {
        treeSize++;
        AllPlayers->root = AllPlayers->insert(AllPlayers->root, pl,NULL);
    }

    int insert(Player* pl)
    {
        if (!(AllPlayers->findNode(AllPlayers->root,pl)))
        {

            AllPlayers->root = AllPlayers->insert(AllPlayers->root,pl,NULL);
            treeSize++;
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int remove(Player* pl)
    {
        AllPlayers->root = AllPlayers->remove(AllPlayers->root,pl);
        treeSize--;
        return  treeSize;
    }
};

class HashTable{
    public:
    int size;
    int numOfKeys;
    Cell* table;
    int cars[4];
    //static void resize(HashTable &ht);
    static void reinsert(Cell* new_table, int new_size, Node<Player*> *data);
    HashTable() : size(10), numOfKeys(0) {
        table = new Cell[10];
    }
    ~HashTable() { delete[] table; }
```

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean? What error do you get?

Comment: If `std::vector` is not available, `HashTable() : size(10), numOfKeys(0),table(new Cell[10]) { }` is what I would do. There is nothing wrong with either of your approaches by themselves.

Comment: std::vector is not available, I have no error , but I cant see the array , there is an image now

Comment: Are you expecting a listing of all of the items in the array? If so you're out of luck. Pointers only know where something is. They do no know how many there are.

Comment: You seem to want an array of 10 elements. If so, do it the same way you did it for cars, i.e. Cell table[10]; If it is a run time determined size, your basic choices are std::vector, std::unique_ptr (or shared_ptr) to array, or raw pointer. In that order they take increasing care for proper handling re constructors, assignment ops, move functions and destructors. How you might inspect their contents in the debugger will vary. For the pointer cases, you will also want a member to save their allocated size.

Comment: @AviBerger You probably mean "...take DECREASING care".

Comment: @BitTickler perhaps I was ambiguous. I meant std::vector takes the least care/work and from there you have more work to get it right with the raw pointer version taking the most care. So care/code required increasing as you progress through the list.

Comment: The image you posted is just because that's how the IDE displays the data. The IDE doesn't know if it's a pointer to a single Cell, or a pointer to an array. Not sure which IDE you are using, but in VS, you can add a watch, then edit the watch and add `,10` to specify it's pointing to an array of size 10.

Comment: @AviBerger Now I get your view on it. I read it as "std::vector takes less care of proper handling" ... compared to a raw pointer. But you meant: With a vector you need to spend less extra care in the handling. :) Languages are hard....

Answer (score 0):

Fear not! You have an array of ten `Cell`s pointed at by `table`.

`table` is a pointer. It holds an address, nothing more. A pointer knows only where an object is (note that the object may have been subsequently destroyed, a pointer has no way of knowing, or the pointer may not have been initialized). If the object referenced to by the pointer is an array, the pointer has no way to know how many items are in the array. The IDE cannot show that there are ten items in the array pointed at by `table` because all it knows is the pointer and the pointer does not know. If you want the IDE to display what is in those ten `Cell`s, you need to set up what are commonly called "watch expressions" for each subobject in the array or play games with casting to tell the watch expression how to interpret the  object at the pointer.

`cars` is an array. Arrays represent the whole whole array. They know their size, their dimensions and all of the data in the array. The IDE can show you all of the items in the `cars` array because `cars` knows all that there is to know.

If you know you will always and forever have 10 `Cell`s, get rid of the pointer and define an array. If you don't know the size, you'll have to live with what the IDE can show you.

Side note: Some IDEs are smart enough to interpret a `std::vector` and can display the objects in the `std::vector`. Consider using `std::vector` instead of a dynamic array where possible. Intelligent handing in IDEs is but a small benefit of `std::vector`.

Side note: When I say *object*, I mean it in [the C++ definition of object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object), not in the OOP sense of an instance of a class.